# Unfortunately GluonApplication has stopped

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I successfully bulid apk from gluon mobile in netbean. When I run it on real device i t appears unfortunately app has stopped

> ### ---------- Build.gradile
>
> ```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         jcenter()
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.3.10'
>     }
> }
>
> apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'
>
> repositories {
>     jcenter()
>     maven {
>         url 'http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases'
>     }
> }
>
> mainClassName = 'com.gradle1.Gradle1'
>
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.gluonhq:charm:5.0.0'
>     androidCompile 'org.glassfish:javax.json:1.0.4'
> }
>
> jfxmobile {
>     javafxportsVersion = '8.60.9'
>     downConfig {
>         version = '3.8.0'
>         // Do not edit the line below. Use Gluon Mobile Settings in your project context menu instead
>         plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'statusbar', 'storage'
>     }
>     android {
>         compileSdkVersion = '21'
>         buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"
>         manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
>         androidSdk = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Android\\android-sdk'
>     }
> }
> ```

---

### Logcat ouput

> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime: Process:
>   com.gluonapplication, PID: 23061
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:578)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4707)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1406)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5452)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:671)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/lib/arm,
>   /data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:984)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:573)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  ... 9 more
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  Suppressed:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:      at
>   java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:      at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:      at
>   java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:      at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:      ... 12 more
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.360 23061 23061 E AndroidRuntime:  Caused by:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class
>   loader; no stack trace available
>
> 08-27 00:55:57.363  1173  2100 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing
>   activity com.gluonapplication/javafxports.android.FXActivity

Comment: That means that an exception occurred. The best way to find out is by having a look at the console. From a terminal go to the android sdk folder, enter platform-tools, and with your device plugged run `adb logcat -v threatime`. Then open the app and check the console for the possible exception.

Comment: should i turn usb debug on?

Comment: Yes, you need USB debugging on.

Comment: ok i got this 08-26 22:58:00.135 19435 19435 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFo
undException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" o
n path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/base.apk"],nativ
eLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.gluonapplication-1/lib/arm, /data/app/com.glu
onapplication-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]

Comment: Please can you help me solved it

Comment: Edit your question and post your build.gradle file and also the full exception you get from logcat

Comment: i can't submit the edit

Comment: Placing the Android SDK under Program Files is not a good idea, as it usually requires permissions to install anything. Android includes its own local repository for instance, and that might fail at that location. Can you move it to a different folder?

Comment: Please can you give me your Facebook link for further discussion

Comment: So that is the only problem

Comment: Yes, i did it i move it to another folder but still the same problem

Comment: Have you done a full cleanup of your project? Run `./gradlew clean`, and also remove `.gradle` folder from your project. Then try again. Maybe you can try newer Android platforms? So far 21 is quite old.